# MYSQL Group By and Order By

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm trying with this:

```
SELECT id, content, vote_up, vote_down, timestamp FROM posts ORDER BY vote_up DESC GROUP BY MONTH(timestamp)
```

Can anyone see a reason why this wouldnt work, my timestamp column is of the type TIMESTAMP

However nothing is echoing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello i am not 100% shure but try this way:

```
SELECT id, content, vote_up, vote_down, MONTH(timestamp) as themonth FROM posts ORDER BY vote_up DESC GROUP BY themonth
```

Comment: thats because "timestamp"... like Marc B explained... you should rename that field

Answer (score 0):

`timestamp` is a reserved word in MySQL, so most likely your query isn't even executing, hence not seeing anything. This implies that you have no error handling in your code.

Fix the query by either renaming the field to something else, or enclosing the word `timestamp` in backticks (`), which 'escapes' reserved words in MySQL.

Then add some error handling to your code so you can capture things like your query failing.